# string containing a mobile number getting stored in its exponential format in the csv file from a ruby program

Tags: ruby, csv

Hi I am working on a small ruby program which maps mobile numbers to the respective states of india.

This is basically done by looking at the first 4 digits of the number.
The code is working fine, the only problem is when I store the output to a csv file, the mobile number which is in the format "+919845632174" is getting stored in its exponential form with '+' character removed.

I need it to be stored exactly the way it is.

Also since I am a newbiew in ruby, if any of you can suggest a better way of doing this or a correct ruby style of doing this, then please leave your answers.

My code is

```
require 'csv'
numbers=CSV.read('mapping.csv',headers:false)
records=Hash.new
output=Hash.new
numbers.each{|key,value| records[key]=value}
file=File.read('sample.txt')
file=file.split("\n")
file.each do |number|
    if !records[number[3,4]].nil?
        output[number]=records[number[3,4]]
    end
end
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") {|csv| output.each {|key,value| csv << [key,value] } }
```

Here is how the output hash looks like:

```
{
"+919785006060"=>"RJ", "+918884992121"=>"KA", "+918800220163"=>"DL", "+919741645921"=>"KA", "+919891548590"=>"DL", "+919579594956"=>"MH", "+919892587868"=>"MU"
}
```

Comment: can you show us what the `output` hash looks like before you write to csv (just a few entries is fine).

Comment: Anthony I have added the output hash, you can have a look now

Comment: Is this a Ruby or an Excel issue?

Comment: It's turned into an excel issue @Stefan - I should have caught that early on.

Comment: See [How can I stop Excel from eating my delicious CSV files and excreting useless data?](http://superuser.com/q/234997/273967)

Comment: That seems to be an interesting link, will go through it.Thanks Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Excel tries to understand what is put to the cells and render accordingly. What it sees is a large number with 'plus' sign, and it treats it as a number in mathematical meaning - this is where it starts to render that with mathematical representation (9.19847E+11).

There might be a workaround for this, where you can explicitly say "Hey Excel! Render the cell value as-is!". Try modify your code generating CSV as follows:

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") {|csv| output.each {|key,value| csv << ['="'+key+'"',value] } }
```

In general, you should try to wrap your phonenumbers with:

`="+ 918884992121",RJ`

With syntax like this, it shouldn't try to "parse and understand" the value, it'll just render it.

**Provided solution is only to make output better to read in Excel**

You have to be aware of what will be stored in your CSV document. It won't be the plain phonenumber as before and if you want to be able to process the file again later, you have to strip the syntax of `="..."` while processing.

If this is something you can live with - you can use the workaround. I'm afraid there is no other way to make it work with plain CSV.

*I'm not really able to test the solution on my own at the moment, but give it a try and let me know!*

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel Dawczak, it gives the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

So with your current code, the output of the csv is flat like this:

```
+919785006060,RJ
+918884992121,KA
...
```

By using `forced_quotes: true` you'll get csv output like this:

```
"+919785006060","RJ"
"+918884992121","KA"
...
```

The code to do that just requires a slight modification.  [force_quotes: true](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) enables you to wrap all of the contents you push into the csv with quotes.  This will usually force programs like excel to read it as a string rather than try to figure out what data-type it is.

```
require 'csv'

outputs = {
"+919785006060"=>"RJ", "+918884992121"=>"KA", "+918800220163"=>"DL", "+919741645921"=>"KA", "+919891548590"=>"DL", "+919579594956"=>"MH", "+919892587868"=>"MU"
}

CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb', { force_quotes: true } ) do |csv|
  outputs.each do |k, v|
    csv << [k, v]
  end
end
```

I had to use excel's import wizard to get it to output like this:

[image: excel output]

If you don't want to use excels import wizard you can force this behavior by adding quotes.  (Note: I'm no excel expert but there appears to be conventions regarding this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/867101/excel-adds-double-quotes-on-csv-export) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da?rq=1)):

```
CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb', { force_quotes: true } ) do |csv|
  outputs.each do |k, v|
    csv << ['"' + k + '"', v]
  end
end
```

In excel 2010 that comes through like this:

[image: with extra quotes]

Comment: Anthony it's still the same with your code as well.This is how it is getting stored 9.19847E+11 in the column

Comment: @Vivek : If the output hash you provided is correct then Anthony's solution should work for you.

Comment: @VivekNayyar - sadly with excel 2010 I had to go through the import wizard for it to display correctly.  Excel tries to be too smart sometimes. I'm seeing if there's a way to fix this though it seems less to do with your ruby code now and more to do with excel.

Comment: limekin, I even tried the exact code that Anthony gave, its still the same output in csv

Comment: Anthony, Yes that;s one way of doing it, but is there no other way we can display it properly

Comment: I've updated my answer and included some extra links that are worth reading.  You run into a dangerous scenario coercing csv files for presentation layers because the moment you start adding all sorts of extras to make it display-some-way, it starts becoming less machine-readable.  Just my 2cents

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony. I tried your workaround for this as well, but Pawel Dawczak solution works the best in my case. But thank you so much for your suggestions.